# Flink watermark is negative

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was trying to assign timestamp and watermarks to a stream by implementing the `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks`, inside the function, it implements:

```
override def getCurrentWatermark: Watermark = {
    // this guarantees that the watermark never goes backwards.
    val potentialWM = currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness
    if (potentialWM >= lastEmittedWatermark) lastEmittedWatermark = potentialWM

    new Watermark(lastEmittedWatermark)
  }

  override def extractTimestamp(element: T, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    val timestamp = element.streamTime // something exists in the stream
    if (timestamp > currentMaxTimestamp) currentMaxTimestamp = timestamp
    timestamp
  }
```

However, I still got watermarks of the default value `-9223372036854775808`, and when I tried to add printing inside both functions, I found only `println` inside `extractTimestamp` was printed, which is saying function of `getCurrentWatermark` was never called.

The implementations seem to be right, because the same code was able to run on another script(some code not written by me).

*PS: It's not the first time that I encountered negative watermark, what I found is that after a certain period of time, the watermark will go positive, however I am still quite confused what happened at the beginning.*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that You are using `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermark` which does not generate watermarks per event but in intervals. Whenever You are using `AssingerWithPeriodicWatermark` You should set call the `setTheAutowatermarkInterval` on the execution environment. The value that You provide there will be the interval that the `getCurrentWatermark` will be called with. 
If You haven't set it then the method will never be called, thus You will never have a watermark changed.
For testing and learning, You can consider using `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermark` as this will simply emit watermark for each event.

EDIT: 
As it was mentioned below this answer, the default value for `autowatermarkInterval` is actually 200 ms. Also, using the `AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermark` doesn't mean You need to emit the Watermark for each event, but the method for emitting them will be called for each event. If You don't want to emit the Watermark then the method should simply return `null`.

Comment: That's not quite correct. The default value of the autoWatermarkInterval is 200msec -- so the current watermark will remain negative until the job has been running for 200msec, at which point getCurrentWatermark will be called.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I was sure that there was no default value. Could You share the link to docs that confirm this ?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/fa4ee95f07bcb58f1f6d1ca6fa04a37f771e05c0/flink-table/flink-sql-client/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/client/config/entries/ExecutionEntry.java#L243

Comment: Also, while with AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermark you can emit a watermark for every event, it doesn't have to be used that way. You can return null whenever you don't want to emit a watermark.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was the fact that it is actually called per each event ;) Perhaps, I wasn't clear in that. I will update the post.

Comment: Hi, I found it is caused by `autowatermarkInterval`, my default value is not 200ms, but 0. It is also in the base class `private long autoWatermarkInterval = 0;`

Comment: If You think the answer was correct, please accept it :)